# Drawing a graph of three nodes such that $\forall x \in V : \forall y \ (x, y) \in E $ (and two variants)

Tags: graph-theory

How will these three graphs look like? It's said that each have 3 nodes. If the three graphs fulfill the following rules, how can I draw them? I still cannot interpret what the statements below mean.

$$G_1 : \forall x \in V : \forall y \in V \ (x, y) \in E $$
$$G_2 : \exists x \in V : \forall y \in V \ (x, y) \in E $$
$$G_3 : \exists x \in V : \forall y \in V \ (x, y) \notin E $$

Comment: $G_1$ is like a complete graph, and $G_2$ is like a star graph...

Comment: how did you come up to that conclusion. Can you explain please?

Comment: $G_1$: For each vertex (node) $x$ we know there is an edge $(x, y)$ between it and any other graph vertex $y$.

Comment: $G_2$: There is a vertex $x$ such that there is an edge $(x, y)$ between it and any other graph vertex $y$.

Answer (score 0):

**Case** $G_1$: A complete graph is a graph in which each pair of graph vertices is connected by an edge  [[Ref]](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteGraph.html). It seems that your $G_1$ following this definition.

[image]